# prompt for users to browse database connection if current database connection fails

Tags: database, vb.net, database-connection, localserver

I am building a data-entry program in vb.net that 5 people will share using, and I have problems setting the right database connection. It would do basic things like: pulling up the stock units, save job, load jobs operations.

The database I'm using is Access database (.mdb). This database will be located in a local server drive (mine is in Z drive) and the connection string looks like this

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="Z:\Jimmy's Files\Quality Enclosures.mdb"
```

This works fine on my computer, but the problem is it does not work on my coworkers computer.

d (\dc-qenclosures) (Z:)  is the loacation to my local server drive, but on my coworker's computer, it is set up as
d (\dc-qenclosures) (Q:).

So, whenever I open the program on my co-worker's computer, it gives me an error saying that the database `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="Z:\Jimmy's Files\Quality Enclosures.mdb"` does not exist (which makes sense because it is not under Z: on his computer)

I know how to use the `OpenFileDialog` to browse for mbd files.. but how do I set this as the new database connection?
I want to create a properties menu to set the database location.

This is the code I have so far to browse for the database file

```
Private Sub RadButton6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadButton6.Click

    Dim myStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()

    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "mdb files (*.mdb)|*.mdb|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()
            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & openFileDialog1.FileName
                con.ConnectionString = myConString
                con.Open()
            End If
        Catch Ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Cannot read file from disk. Original error: " & Ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Check this again, since we need to make sure we didn't throw an exception on open. 

            If (myStream IsNot Nothing) Then
                myStream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use an `ODBC` datasource for all users?

Comment: Or, if over a network(same domain), put it in a shared folder and use a UNC path.

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to Vb.net, so I didn't know I could do that. Thank you for the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd second @OneFineDay's suggestion of trying the UNC path first, but to answer your main question of browsing for and saving a database path, you may want to look at storing elements of your connection string in `My.Settings`, so you could make the path a user-level setting. There's an MSDN article with examples here:
[Using My.Settings in Visual Basic 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379611%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In short, you'd have the code sample you shared save the value to `My.Settings.DataPath` (or whatever you decide to call the setting). Then when you're connecting to the database and need the connection string, you'd make it read from `My.Settings.DataPath`.

Of course, that'd store your path to the database in a plain-text `app.config` file by default, so you'll want to be conscious of that and take appropriate steps if there are any security concerns around your app or database.

Comment: Thanks, A.Franklin, exactly what I needed. I needed to know how to store as settings as well as know how to set UNC path. Thanks for the help!